# Adding firebase to libgdx project built with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, firebase, build.gradle

Here is my gradle.build. Im trying to add the firebase dependency so I can play with the simple login functions but gradle looks like it cant find the dependency. I copy and pasted what the firebase simple login example said to add to the build.gradle file but im coming up with this error. Included is the build.gradle file and a full stack trace of when I tried to build it from command line.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
        classpath 'com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.10'
    }
}

   dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-simple-login:1.4.1+'
}




allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'my-gdx-game'
        gdxVersion = '1.2.0'
        roboVMVersion = '0.0.14'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

And here is the error:

```
[C:\project\git\board]gradlew.bat build -full-stacktrace --debug --info
Connected to the daemon. Dispatching Build{id=6b7b428a-cace-4920-b1d3-5480d00814ac.1, currentDir=C:\project\git\board} request.
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 6548). The daemon log file: C:\Users\Jim\.gradle\daemon\1.11\daemon-6548.out.log
Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ef019ac1-9b19-4435-a4ed-ea777cdc126e,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Jim\.gradle\daemon,pid=6548,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xms128m,-Xmx256m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\project\git\board\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\project\git\board\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'board', project ':android', project ':core', project ':desktop', project ':html', project ':ios']
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
In-memory cache of C:\project\git\board\.gradle\1.11\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin: Size{0}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
In-memory cache of C:\project\git\board\.gradle\1.11\taskArtifacts\outputFileStates.bin: Size{0}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
In-memory cache of C:\project\git\board\.gradle\1.11\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin: Size{0}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
In-memory cache of C:\project\git\board\.gradle\1.11\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin: Size{0}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
Evaluating root project 'board' using build file 'C:\project\git\board\build.gradle'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\project\git\board\build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'board'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.firebase:firebase-client:1.0.16+] on root project 'board'.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'board'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:177)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:28)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.firebase:firebase-client:1.0.16+] on root project 'board'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:804)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1096)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:697)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
        at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:348)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at build_4hs70848rpv3eftlj2nom94sbr$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\project\git\board\build.gradle:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.dependencies(AbstractProject.java:926)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:225)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:804)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1096)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at build_4hs70848rpv3eftlj2nom94sbr.run(C:\project\git\board\build.gradle:15)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.798 secs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used Firebase but I just ran a quick gradle build and this worked

You need to add the dependency to the project that you are going to use it in.
Add the dependency to the core project like this;

```
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    // add firebase
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client:1.0.16'
}
```

I just ran a build and changed the firebase version number to "1.0.16" as shown here [Firebase Quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html) and removed the "+" and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks, this added the client, I added the SimpleLogin dependency as well. Ran into some duplicate files but was able to exclude them so now its up and working, sort of, I think I also need some JSON jars added but that is another problem.