# How to use Firebase in Libgdx?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, libgdx, game-engine

I'm developing a game using Libgdx, I don't know how to use Firebase in my game, because, my game is multi-platform, while Firebase not support for Libgdx. Anyone used Firebase in Libgdx? Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193386/adding-firebase-to-libgdx-project-built-with-gradle  , please check this link somebody already answered for the same kind of question. please go through the above link

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no 3rd party library (or even in development, as I know). You have to work with [Interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) and then write native code for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and MOE/RoboVM (I got it working with MOE).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for that: https://github.com/mk-5/gdx-fireapp